# Error with SQL CONVERT GETDATE() for leap years

Tags: sql-server, dateadd, getdate

What I'm trying to do here is add a time component to GETDATE() since it's being converted to varchar(25). This is my statement, how would I do it?

```
CONVERT(Varchar(25),YEAR(GETDATE())-1)
```

Would it be something along CONVERT(Varchar(25),year(getDate()) -1)

This CONVERT is actually a part of:

```
DATEADD(m, 6,CAST(CONVERT(Varchar(25),MONTH(tblDateApt. Date)) +
'/' + CONVERT(Varchar(25),DAY(tblDateApt. Date)) 
+ '/' + CONVERT(Varchar(25),YEAR(GETDATE())-1)  As DateTime))
```

The problem is when I run this statement on a leap year date I get an error. I'm trying to add a time to getDate before it gets casted as DATETIME

EDIT 2

I'm simply trying to make this give return a value...

```
select DATEADD(m, 6,CAST(CONVERT(Varchar(25),MONTH('2/29/2016')) + '/' + CONVERT(Varchar(25),DAY('2/29/2016')) + '/' + CONVERT(Varchar(25),YEAR(GETDATE())-1)   As DateTime))
```

Comment: Seems like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. what is your goal?

Comment: When I do the CONVERT(varchar25),year(GetDate())-1) on a leap year, I get an error because it tries to go back to 2/29/2015 - but I know if I maybe added a time component to it, it would simply go back to 2/28/2016. When i do a SELECT dateadd(yy,-1,'2/29/2016') it gives me 2/28/2016 but it's not working in this query

Comment: what is the data like in tblDAteApt? Can you show some sample inputs of teh records you are having trouble with and the expected output of teh DAteAdd?

Comment: @HLGEM ALl dates are datetime. When I run this DATEADD on a leap date, in this case '2/29/2016' i get an error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Again, what is your goal? seems like you are going for the wrong solution, so please describe the problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled my goal is to add a timecomponent to GETDATE right before I cast is AS DATETIME, so this way when i go back -1 from leap year '2/29/2016' it will show me a date of 2/28/2016 - rather than getting an error that the conversion of varchar datatype to a datetime datatype resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: So you have a date in your database, and you want to get that same date, but with a year part that is one year before the current year?

Comment: @ZoharPeled i think that's what the issue might be. because i convert it to varchar i think its looking for 2/29/2015 if I had a time component with it, it would most likely go back to 2/28/2015

Comment: @ZoharPeled if you look at the DATEADD i'm breaking apart a date into 3 component - DateApt month and day, but I'm using YEAR from GETDATE(). I'm actually not sure what the solution can be. I know that when I run this DATEADD I get an error with 2/29/2016 i'm trying to find a way of not getting the error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled please see edit

Comment: I hope I understand the target date now. please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the date into strings and rebuild it into date is almost never the correct solution.

Assuming I understand the problem, you want to get the dates from your database, and manipulate the year part to be a year before the current year.

Try this:

```
SELECT  tblDateApt.[Date], 
        DATEADD(Month, 
                6, 
                DATEADD(YEAR, 
                        YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 - YEAR(tblDateApt.[Date]),
                        tblDateApt.[Date])
        )
FROM tblDateApt
```

Edited to get the date of 6 months after the date in the database after manipulating it to last year.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu!

Comment: if you have a second, can you please just explain the 2nd DATEADD that you have?

Comment: It's just to add the 6 months. It can be done by a single dateadd, but then you have to calculate the number of months between the last year and the year in the database. this way it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This will leave you with DateTime value taken from `tblDateApt.Date` decreased by one year and increased by 6 months (as per your intent):

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,
               6,
               DATEADD(year, 
                       YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(tblDateApt.date) - 1, 
                       tblDateApt.date
                      )
              )
```

Avoid any conversions to and from text content.

Comment: I need to as I'm breaking up the DateApt - into DateApt day, and month but i'm using GETDATE to get the year - See the end of DateAdd right before 'as DateTime'

Comment: @FatBoySlim7 – Then you can use `DATEADD(y, tblDateApt.date, YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(tblDateApt.date))` to adjust the year.